# REact chart js 2 version 3.8.2 pie chart slice click event not working

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

Below is my configuration: I'm using `getElementsAtEvent`event to get pie slice click event. When clicking on slice control not reaching to my method that we are looking for.

```
{
    "chart.js": "^3.8.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
    "pubsub-js": "^1.9.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0"
    }
```

````
<Pie data={this.state.PieChartData} options={this.state.options} getElementsAtEvent={this.HandleClickOnSlice} />```

and here's my `HandleClickOnSlice` method. I tried with the arrow function as well. Mouse-click on pie chart slice control not reaching to function definition

    
  HandleClickOnSlice(event){
        try {
            var SliceText = event[0]["_view"]["label"];
        }
        catch (error) {

        }
    }
````